# ¿Cómo crear una función usando como argumento una variable de un objeto survey.design?

Tags: r, function, survey

Siguiendo el ejemplo que se usa en la documentación del paquete.

```
library(survey)
data(api)
dclus1<-svydesign(id=~dnum, weights=~pw, data=apiclus1, fpc=~fpc)

svyby(~api99, ~stype, dclus1, svymean)
```

Que resulta.

```
  stype    api99       se
E     E 607.7917 22.81660
H     H 595.7143 41.76400
M     M 608.6000 32.56064
```

Asimismo, pero si quiero crear una función que me permita hacer lo mismo, pero para cada una de las variables numéricas. Por ejemplo, creo la siguiente función

```
f1<-function(x){
  x<-enquo(x)
  svyby(~!!x, ~stype, dclus1, svymean)
}
```

Lo hago como si se usara dplyr. Y lo evaluo para la variable `api99`.

```
f1(sym("api99"))
```

Pero, me resulta:

```
! Quosures can only be unquoted within a quasiquotation context.

# Bad: list(!!myquosure)

# Good: dplyr::mutate(data, !!myquosure)
```

Sé que está mal porque he creado la función como si fuese a usar dplyr.

¿Cómo podría crear la función? La cual me permita solo colocar el nombre de la columna y se obtenga los resultados esperados.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error nos está diciendo que no podemos hacer un "unquote" de un "quosure" si el  contexto no es de "quasiquotation" (perdón pero me es imposible traducir al español estos conceptos). Básicamente no podemos usar `!!` en una función que no implemente "quasiquotation", como es el caso de muchas de las funciones de `dplyr` pero como no es el caso de `svyby()`. Un ejemplo básico similar a lo que estás haciendo, que si funcionaría sería algo así:

```
f0 <- function(x) {
  arg <- ensym(x)
  paste("Recibí por parametro:", arg)
}

f1<-function(x){f0(x)}
f2<-function(x){f0(!!x)}

variable <- "Este es el valor"

f1(variable)
[1] "Recibí por parametro: x"

f2(variable)
[1] "Recibí por parametro: Este es el valor"
```

En este caso `f0` haría las veces de `svyby()` si esta implementara "quasiquotation". Y lo implementa mediante `ensym()` de la biblioteca `rlang` sin embargo hay muchas funciones que son capaces de entender `!!`.

Ahora bien, para lo que creo que buscas, ni siquiera necesitas usar evaluación no estándar, ya que estás pasando una cadena, bien podrías hacer algo así:

```
f1<-function(x){
  formula = as.formula(paste0("~", x))
  svyby(formula, ~stype, dclus1, svymean)
}

f1("api99")
```

O si quieres usar `NSE`:

```
f1 <- function(x){
  arg <- ensym(x)
  formula = as.formula(paste0("~", arg))
  svyby(formula, ~stype, dclus1, svymean)
}

f1(api99)
```

Y, ahora podrías usar eventualmente `!!`:

```
variable <- "api99"
f1(!!variable)
```